# Facebook canvas redirects to main facebook page

Tags: facebook, redirect, canvas

I coded a stub application for Facebook.
When I'm trying access the app url (http://apps.facebook.com/myappname) it all works fine. It works from other servers as well.
However, a specific co-worker of mine is also trying to access it and he gets redirected to facebook.com
A day ago he was able to log-in, and we are not aware of any changes.

Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: is the application is sandbox mode and is this user listed in the roles section of the application?

Comment: Yes, it's sandbox, and he's listed as a Developer.

Answer (score 0):

This is common for when you don't have the required SSL server's url in the app settings.  That other user that was redirected has allow only https set in his user preferences.  Since you have no https version set, then he gets redirected away.  If you do have the SSL server's url in your app settings, then the SSL cert may be bad.  Many people try to get away with using a "fake" cheap SSL cert.  The cert must be a real (read: expensive) one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,but we've already tried that. It's not an SSL error, the user is not using the 'Secure Browsing' feature. When I actually delete the https:// from the address bar, it works. But he gets redirected to facebook.com.